# Delphi RES and Switching Git Branches

Tags: windows, git, delphi, pascal

I'm using this function to get the current version of my program.
My problem is when I'm checking out/switching to my local branches on Git, The dwFileVersionLS is overwritten.

Take this scenario,

I Have two Branches,

'Branch1' - GetFileVersion returns '6.7.5.21'

'Branch2' - GetFileVersion returns '6.7.5.25'

My current branch is 'Branch2' and I rebuild my application, This will increment my 'Branch2' GetFileVersion to '6.7.5.26'.

I committed the changes on my 'Branch2' and check out my 'Branch1' and GetFileVersion returns '6.7.5.26'. (which should be '6.7.5.21' since I didnt do any changes on this branch)

(Edit) Also When I rebuild my application on 'Branch1' this will increment my build version to '6.7.5.22'.

```
function TGSGGlobal.GetFileVersion: String;
var
  VerInfoSize: Cardinal;
  VerValueSize: Cardinal;
  Dummy: Cardinal;
  PVerInfo: Pointer;
  PVerValue: PVSFixedFileInfo;
begin
     Result := '';
     VerInfoSize := GetFileVersionInfoSize(PChar(Application.ExeName), Dummy);
     GetMem(PVerInfo, VerInfoSize);
  try
    if GetFileVersionInfo(PChar(Application.ExeName), 0, VerInfoSize, PVerInfo) then
      if VerQueryValue(PVerInfo, '\', Pointer(PVerValue), VerValueSize) then
        with PVerValue^ do
          Result := Format('v%d.%d.%d.%d', [
            HiWord(dwFileVersionMS), //Major
            LoWord(dwFileVersionMS), //Minor
            HiWord(dwFileVersionLS), //Release
            LoWord(dwFileVersionLS)]); //Build
  finally
    FreeMem(PVerInfo, VerInfoSize);
  end;
end;
```

The Application is included in Git Reporistory.

(Edit) I Found out that the projects .res file is not refreshed/updated when switching branches. I need to reopen my project in order to get my branches current build version.

Comment: The version number is stored in your project's `.res` file. Is that file in version control? If you change branches, you will get the version that's in that branch, and your version numbers will be modified accordingly. If the .res file is excluded from version control, the version number will just be incremented on every build, regardless whether you switch branches.

Comment: Hi @GolezTrol, I found out that everytime I need to switch branches I need to reopen my project in order to get the version in that branch. The .res file is not automatically updated when you switch bracnhes on Git.

Comment: Yes, that could be the case. Personally I don't like to have that version number in git at all. Our projects don't automatically increment the build number. Instead, our CI server, which builds the final version, keeps track of the number. That way we got rid of this issue. But that's personal preference, of course.